# How to merge varying sized Lists into a Dictionary with Zip?

Tags: c#

I am messing around with Zip and I am slightly confused as to how it works. I can't get it the way I want. I have to lists that look like this:

```
List<string> names = new List<string> 
{ 
    "Mark", "Chris", "Alex", "Default Name", "Jerilyn"
};

List<string> colors = new List<string> 
{
    "Green", "Blue", "Red", "Orange"
};
```

When I use Zip here:

```
var dict = names.Zip(colors, (k, v) => new { Key = k, Value = v })
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

I get the output of `Mark -> Green, Chris -> Blue, Alex -> Red, Default Name -> Orange` but I want to add a default value for all 'Default Name' instances so it will be like:

```
Mark -> Green, Chris -> Blue, Alex -> Red, Default Name -> 'Default Color', Jerilyn -> Orange
```

But, I don't understand why Zip would only add the first 4 elements of the Keys. I know the Values only has 4 values but I was expecting all five values to be in the collection and the last entry being null or an empty string. That would make the change easier.

Comment: `But, I don't understand why Zip would only add the first 4 elements of the Keys.` Because that is how it is documented to work - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2. You want `ZipLongest` - https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/ZipLongest.cs / https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/.

Comment: So, in essence you need to use `Where` to exclude the `Default Name` then `ZipLongest` then `Concat` to add the `Default Name` back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a two step process because you don't know what colour `"Default Name"` will be.

Here's how:

```
var names = new List<string>
{
    "Mark", "Chris", "Alex", "Default Name", "Jerilyn"
};

var colors = new List<string>
{
    "Green", "Blue", "Red", "Orange"
};

var map = names.Zip(colors, (n, c) => new { n, c }).ToDictionary(x => x.n, x => x.c);

map = names.ToDictionary(x => x, x => map.ContainsKey(x) ? map[x] : map["Default Name"]);
```

That gives:

```
Key          | Value  
------------ | -------
Mark         | Green  
Chris        | Blue   
Alex         | Red    
Default Name | Orange 
Jerilyn      | Orange
```

Comment: @Cuphead - Perhaps either don't delete comments or delete all the comments?